# eloquent laravel using with variable

Tags: laravel

i have project on laravel 5.3
and this is my function inside the controller

```
public function CustomerReportGet(Request $request) 
{
    $full = Voucherreceive::where('voucherreceive_customer_id','=',$request->customer_id)->sum('voucherreceive_amount');
    if($request->from_date == '' and $request->to_date == '')
        $data = Voucherreceive::where('voucherreceive_customer_id','=',$request->customer_id)->get();
    elseif($request->from_date <> '' or $request->to_date <> '')
    {
        $data = Voucherreceive::where('voucherreceive_customer_id','=',$request->customer_id)->
                whereBetween('created_at',array($request->from_date,$request->to_date));
    }
    return $data;
}
```

how can i send the $full variable with $data ..
i tried to do this

```
            $data = Voucherreceive::where('voucherreceive_customer_id','=',$request->customer_id)->with('full')->get();
```

but i still have internal server error ..
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before return, you can make an array  with full & data as it's element and then return this new array.
    `return array($full, $data);`

Or you can define the relationship  in the model to use 'with'